# Using JSON returned from an API to populate a variable used by a React-Table table component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write this React component that connects to an API that returns JSON.

The API returns JSON results that look like this small example:

JSON:

```
{
    "id": 22,
    "gameTitle": "The Haunted Plains II",
    "startDate": "2020-03-31T12:49:50.009",
    "endDate": "2020-04-04T04:00:00",
    "description": "A simple bitmap style RPG",
    "gameUrl": "https://yourgames.org/1/55/3",
    "isOpen": true,
    "gameFaqId": 25,
    "gameTypeId": 3,
    "gameCharClasses": ["Bard", "Theif", "Warrior", "Wizard", "Cleric"]
},

{
    "id": 25,
    "gameTitle": "Downhill Mountain Biking Pro",
    "startDate": "2020-02-12T11:22:30.011",
    "endDate": "2020-05-02T03:11:00",
    "description": "A side-scrolling, downhill mountaining biking game",
    "gameUrl": "https://yourgames.org/3/43/6",
    "isOpen": true,
    "gameFaqId": 11,
    "gameTypeId": 6,
    "gameCharClasses": ["Beginner", "Pro", "Super Star"]
}
```

I want to put the data into the 'gameListing' variable that have defined as 'const gameListing'.

Then I have a function called makeData that is called by the main app which is using a React library called 'react-table'.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(
            'https://localhost:44376/api/projects',
        );
        setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

const range = len => {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
};

const gameListing = data.map(g => {
  return {
    id: g.id,
    gameTitle: g.gameTitle,
    startDate: g.startDate,
    endDate: g.endDate,
    description: g.description,
    gameUrl: g.gameUrl,
    isOpen: g.isOpen,
    gameFaqId: g.gameFaqId,
    gameCharClasses: g.gameCharClasses
  };
});

export default function makeData(lens = [2]) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth]
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...gameListing(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeDataLevel()
}
```

The problem is, after hours of debugging, I can't get it to work.

My latest issue is that it's not displaying any data.

Here is a Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-booth-b7wxg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one problem is youre using .map wrong
you have to pass in a parameter and that parameter is basically like a placeholder to use that has the data within it 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
for example:

```
const gameListing = data.map((elem) => {
  return {
    id: elem.id,
    gameTitle: elem.gameTitle,
    startDate: elem.startDate,
    endDate: elem.endDate,
    description: elem.description,
    gameUrl: elem.gameUrl,
    isOpen: elem.isOpen,
    gameFaqId: elem.gameFaqId,
    gameCharClasses: elem.gameCharClasses
  }
})
```

Does that help or work?

Comment: Thanks I did fix that part in the Code Sandbox.  But now I'm getting an error, "gameListing" is not a function...

Comment: thats weird
ill look at it now
sorry for the slow response

Comment: Oh yeah on line 70
remove the () in front of gameListing
right now you have it like this
```
...gameListing()
```
just remove the ()

Comment: Well that got rid of that error, but now I don't get any results.  I'm expecting to see the two objects that I have in the sample JSON object.

Comment: ohhh when i console.log(gameListing) it returned [object, object]
imma check out why its doing that

Comment: i see why its doing that.
the [object, object] means its an array of two objects.
So in order to get the data you're gonna have to pick one like this
'gameListing[0].gameTitle' since its an array of 2 objects.
its kinda weird, you may have to step thru your code and reorganize it

Comment: Oh ok, well the "makeData" function is supposed to collect as many gameListing objects as called for by the parameter...in this case 2, since I only have 2 objects in the sample JSON. So should I somehow pass a value to it?